# Masks in JSF2 with rich:jQuery?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, mask

I´m trying to input masks in JSF2, in this way:

```
<h:inputText id="cep1" value="#{bean.cepR}" /> <rich:jQuery selector="#cep1" query="mask('99999-999')" timing="domready" />
```

However, It does not happen any error, on the other hand, the masks are not rendered.

Someone knows what iis going ?

If it´s relevant i'm using richfaces 4.3.5

Is there other ways to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention you're using a jQuery plugin. RichFaces 4.3.5 uses jQuery 1.8.3, is the plugin compatible? You can try debugging the JavaScript, if it gets correctly executed then the problem is in the plugin.

Comment: I tried to change the timing for "onload", however, this following error happens:  Cannot convert onload of type class java.lang.String to class org.richfaces.component.JQueryTiming

Comment: Timing can be either "immediate" or "domready" but that shouldn't really be the issue. By default rich:jQuery isn't persistent so if something is happening to the input before you interact with it the mask might be gone.